# VSCode Snippets: Remove Char After Capitalizing?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Is there a way to create a chain of regex to  capitalize a string and than remove all characters `-` from it in Visual Studio Code snippets?

```
    "body": [
        "const ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([a-z])(\\w+)/${1:/upcase}$2  /['-.']//  /g};
    ]
```

**Wanted Result:**
File Name: `user-name.js`
Snippet: `const UserName`

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you just want `"const ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/}"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Exacly what I needed, Thanks!